# What do I do if my dual shock controller has two circle buttons?

Tags: ps4, controllers

My SCUF VANTAGE gaming controller for the PS4 has two circle buttons instead of the usual  <kbd>`△`</kbd> <kbd>`◯`</kbd> <kbd>`✕`</kbd> <kbd>□</kbd>.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the problem? Is it affecting your gameplay? And if so, how?

Comment: Little cousins but I just don’t like and it was $250 bucks

Comment: Is it affecting your gameplay? Do they both map to circle?

Comment: Quick and dirty fix: draw the proper icon on a piece of paper and paste it on top of the button. Proper solution: claim your warranty. This is clearly a defect on arrival.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a gaming-specific problem. Manufacturing defects happen in all sorts of hardware, and solely the fact that this particular piece of hardware is gaming-related does not make it on-topic for this site.

Comment: I disagree with both presented close reasons. The question is/was fairly clear (imo). And as for off-topic,  if a question about a defective controller (*gaming-specific hardware*) is off-topic simply because **all** hardware can have manufacturing defects... Hoo boy, I do not want to open that can of worms. How many questions do we field about software bugs? Software bugs, show-stopping or otherwise exist in all sorts of software...

Answer (score 3):

It is more than likely that this is just a cosmetic problem. During assembly, someone grabbed a second circle button and placed it in a slot intended for one of the other buttons. Pressing it should result in the proper input, much like swapping the keys on a keyboard.

Cosmetic or not, your best option for fixing it is to contact the manufacturer's support (in your case, [the support page for SCUF is here](https://scufgaming.com/s/assist/)). After providing them with whatever information they require (proof of purchase, picture of the defect), they will likely provide details on how to ship it back to them so they can verify the error and send you a replacement. This process may take some time to complete.

Comment: You may even get a free controller out of this. Shipping defective products to the manufacturer is a waste of time and money for something that is just going to be disposed of.

Comment: @studoku Maybe? Wouldn't count on it. A simple button swap wouldn't cost the manufacturer much, and these scuf ones are 'premium' controllers sold at ~$200+ (why in anyone would pay the nearly the cost of a console form single controller, idk). They're more likely to swap the button and re-sell it. If it was a generic controller that only cost $50, maybe.